When do these Algebra Equations have solutions?
I am learning about the Stationary Distributions and Limiting Distributions of Markov Chains (I think these equations are true for both discrete time and continuous time):
$$\text{1) Stationary Distribution:} \quad \pi = \pi P$$
$$ \text{2) Limiting Distribution:} \quad \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \pi = \pi_0 P^n$$
I was just wondering about the following: In both cases, to determine $\pi$ (i.e. the distribution of interest), this is the equivalent of solving a system of algebraic equations. But as know, systems of algebraic equations are not always solvable and sometimes don't always have unique solutions.
So my question is:

Is there some mathematical proof that outlines the necessary conditions for equations 1) and 2) to be solvable and have unique solutions? (e.g. ergodic, aperiodic) Can we mathematically prove this?
Is there some mathematical proof that outlines the necessary conditions for the solution of 1) to be equal to the solution of 2)? Can we mathematically prove this?

Much appreciated!
PS: I think equation 2) is likely more difficult to solve compared to equation 1). Therefore, for a given Markov Chain - if we can know a priori that the solution to equation 1) is equal in theory to the solution of equation 2) ... we can get away with only solving equation 1) and thus greatly simplify our work.

I think this thread is helpful for Case 2).

Thank you! I already commented there already on May 9 :)  I was hoping to see some math behind it...

In the equation $(2)$ the limit is on the wrong side...

@ dan : thanks ... I will try to fix...

It seems this is a studied topic. But since I am a specialist in algebra, but not in the probability theory or Markov chains, I studied my source and to follow it. This is [Gan, Chapter XIII, $\S$6-7.]
We begin from the explicit definitions.

Consider $n$ possible states $S_1,S_2,\dots, S_n$ of a system and a sequence $t_0,t_1,t_2,\dots$ of moments of time.


Let at each of these time moments the system is in exactly one of the states, and $p_{ij}$ is the probability that the system is in a state $S_j$ at a time moment $t_k$, if it is known that at the previous time moment $t_{k-1}$ the system was in a state $T_i$ [I suppose that here is a misprint and there should be $S_i$ instead of $T_i$. AR] ($i,j=1,2,\dots,n$; $k=1,2,\dots$). We should assume that the transition probabilities $p_{ij}$ ($i,j=1,2,\dots,n$) do not depend on the index $k$ (the number of the time moment $t_k$).


It the matrix $P=\|p_{ij}\|^n_1$ is given, that we say that it is given a homogeneous Markov chain with a finite number of its states. Then it is obvious that
$$p_{ij}\ge 0\mbox{ and }\sum_{j=1}^n p_{ij}=1\mbox{ }(i,j=1,2,\dots,n).$$ Such matrix $P$ is called stochastic.

A nonnegative matrix $P\ge 0$ is stochastic iff it has the eigenvector $(1,1,\dots,1)$ with the eigenvalue $1$. By Corollary 1 from Theorem 10, to the eigenvalue with the absolute value $1$ of a stochastic matrix always correspond only elementary divisors of the degree $1$.
A stochastic matrix is correct, if $1$ is its only eigenvalue with the absolute value $1$.
It turns out that for stochastic matrix $P$ there exists $\lim_{n\to\infty} P^n$ iff $P$ is correct,
see [Gan, Chapter XIII, $\S$7] for more details.
References
[Gan] F.R. Gantmacher, The theory of matrices, 2nd(?) edn., in Russian.
PS. I have to go to a seminar soon, so I expect to continue the answer later.
